# A question about Kobayashi hyperbolic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

> Let $X$ be a projective variety with snc divisor $D$ with $K_X+D<0$, which pair $(X,D)$ is log k-stable
>   .Take $\mathcal M$ be the moduli space of log Fano
>   pairs. Then the regular part $\mathcal M'$ of $\mathcal M$ is
>   Kobayashi hyperbolic variety?
>
> I know that when $\mathcal M$ is moduli space of pairs $(X,D)$ of log
>   general types then $\mathcal M'$ is Kobayashi hyperbolic variety.

Comment: What do you mean by the "regular part"?  Do you mean the subset parameterizing log smooth pairs?  Do you mean the smooth locus of $\mathcal{M}$?  Are you considering pairs that satisfy some additional stability property (e.g., K-stable), so that there is actually a moduli space?

Comment: When$\mathcal M$ is a moduli space of pairs $(X,D)$ of log general types then such moduli space exists by the work of G. Schumacher, Moduli space of framed manifolds  http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220050264

Comment: But for Log Fano case , we must assume log K-stability which I have forgotten in my question. By the work of Chi Li it is quasi projective.

Comment: I don't know the existence of such moduli space when $(X,D)$ is log Calabi-Yau. I asked before also. It is very important for me.

Comment: It corresponds to isotriviality notion when you take $\pi:(X,D)\to \mathbb C^*$, since in his case $C^*\setminus \Delta\to \mathcal M$ is constant

Comment: I recommend to see this slide http://www.mat.ufmg.br/~ibero/en/Apresentacoes/kovacs/OuroPreto.pdf. Also The isotriviality conjecture of Campana http://digitool.library.mcgill.ca/webclient/StreamGate?folder_id=0&dvs=1509285246868~881

Comment: Note that when dimension of base is bigger than one, then for hyperbolicity of moduli space we need some algebraic condition on the base ,see for example Kovacs paper,  https://sites.math.washington.edu/~kovacs/papers/Kovacs__Families_over_a_base_with_a_birationally_nef_tangent_bundle.pdf